# How do I transpose every line in a row to multiple columns?

Tags: pandas, dataframe, multiple-columns, data-cleaning, transpose

[data table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BG8fK.png)

From the screenshot you can see that the description column (third row from the right) has a long list of data in every single row, and they read like this in Excel:

```
Color: White
Style: Casual
Pattern Type: Plain
Details: Pocket
Top Type: Tee
Bottom Type: Track Shorts
Neckline: Round Neck
```

How can I use pandas to split this row such that I get a new column for Color, a new column for Style, a new column for Pattern Type, a new column for Details, etc. ?

Thank you for helping out.

I tried using Split() but I couldn't figure out what to call to indicate the data on the next row.

Comment: read notice : [mre] and provide example as text table or code